# Internally, are each react-native's components mapped to each UIKit's classes?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm learning react-native now and have a question.

Are each react-native's components mapped to each UIKit's classes internally?

Flutter, on the other hand, draws the component on its own canvas, not use native ui components. But I think react-native use native ui component with bridge. Are all react components (`View` or `Text` etc.) mapped to native UI components (`UIView` or `UILabel` etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you are correct myfriend.**

> At the highest level, React Native is a way to write React apps that run as native programs. You write your app's code in JavaScript, and React Native bridges that code with native UIView elements.

You can find the complete article : [here](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2017/07/06/React-Native-for-iOS-devs/)